# I lost my iPhone; how can I see my messages?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, messages

I lost my iPhone. I have my Apple ID and password, FaceBook password, phone number and email password. Is it possible for me to view my texts, photos etc. and access them through my MacBook Pro laptop without having my phone?

Comment: The messages of which app do you want to access?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this (assuming your talking about your iMessages).

**Messages app**

On your MacBook Pro:

1. Launch the Messages app
2. Assuming you haven't already signed in previously, then sign in with the same Apple ID you use for your messages on your iPhone

That's all you need to do. Now you can receive and send messages from your MBP.

**Note:** - You'll only get the messages that come through since you've set this up on your MBP. In other words, if you have 5yrs of message history on your iPhone, then you won't get all that history via this process.

**Photos**

If your iPhone was set up to upload photos to iCloud then you can also access these from your MBP.

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences
2. Click on the iCloud preference pane
3. Next to Photos click on the <kbd>Options</kbd> button
4. Now, depending on your situation, select either (or both) iCloud Photo Library and/or My Photo Stream
5. Click <kbd>Done</kbd>

**Note:** What you can access from your Mac will depend on how you had iCloud configured on your iPhone.

**iCloud**

From iCloud preferences you can access other information as well.

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences
2. Click on the iCloud preference pane
3. Go through the various options to select what you want.

**Note:** What you can access from your Mac will depend on how you had iCloud configured on your iPhone.

**Further info**

The following resources will be of help:

- [iCloud Photo Library](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204264)
- [Use messages with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT202549)
- [Set up iCloud on all your devices](https://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/mac.html)
- [Find My iPhone: Use Lost Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19299)